# Maximum float value in php

Tags: php, floating-point

Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the maximum float value for php.  Akin to `FLT_MAX` or `std::numeric_limits< float >::max()` in C / C++?

I am using something like the following:

```
$minimumCost = MAXIMUM_FLOAT_VALUE??;

foreach ( $objects as $object )
{
    $cost = $object->CalculateCost();
    if ( $cost < $minimumCost )
    {
        $minimumCost = $cost;
    }
}
```

(using php 5.2)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The float maximum is platform-dependant, and even though it could be useful to get it, there seems to be no (simple) way to get it. You can however use the `INF` (infinite) constant, which will be bigger than any other value you can ever put in a numeric type, if the goal is only to have a huge placeholder value.

Comment: Yep, the goal is just to have a huge value. Thanks ;)

Comment: But surely when $minimumCost is INF, if ($cost < $minimumCost ) is the same as if (true), and thus pointless.

Comment: @Kzqai that is exactly what you want in some cases, like if you want to find the lowest cost among X entries. Then it's pretty easy to use that if in a foreach($prices as $cost) to find the lowest value. Otherwise you'd have to do something like $minimumCost = $prices[0] and then loop using for($i = 1; $i<count($prices); $i++)

Comment: Ah, sure, it'll be true for the first loop, but not necessarily for subsequent loops, that's fair.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the PHP_FLOAT_MAX predefined constant, I believe.

Comment: Requires PHP 7.2+ `PHP_FLOAT_MAX` (float)
Largest representable floating point number. Available as of `PHP 7.2.0`.  source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: Indeed, very helpful :)