# PHP constant equivalent to DBL_MAX

Tags: php

Is there any PHP constant equivalent to Objective C's `DBL_MAX`? In other words a constant defined with the highest possible double number?

I'm aware of the PHP constant `PHP_INT_MAX`, but is this really the highest possible number in PHP?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2650342?

Comment: It's the higest possible integer - the highest possible float depends on whether you're running 32-bit or 64-bit PHP