# What's the biggest number PHP can handle?

Tags: php

I did run this script and I did get a bit worried when it did spit out this group:

```
1.0284403483258E+62 5.1422017416288E+61 2.5711008708144E+61 1.2855504354072E+61 6.427752177036E+60 3.213876088518E+60 1.606938044259E+60 8.034690221295E+59 4.0173451106475E+59 2.0086725553237E+59 1.0043362776619E+59 5.0216813883093E+58 2.5108406941547E+58 1.2554203470773E+58 6.2771017353867E+57 3.1385508676933E+57 1.5692754338467E+57 7.8463771692334E+56 3.9231885846167E+56 1.9615942923083E+56 9.8079714615417E+55 4.9039857307708E+55 2.4519928653854E+55 1.2259964326927E+55 6.1299821634636E+54 3.0649910817318E+54 1.5324955408659E+54 7.6624777043294E+53 3.8312388521647E+53 1.9156194260824E+53 9.5780971304118E+52 4.7890485652059E+52 2.394524282603E+52 1.1972621413015E+52 5.9863107065074E+51 2.9931553532537E+51 1.4965776766268E+51 7.4828883831342E+50 3.7414441915671E+50 1.8707220957836E+50 9.3536104789178E+49 4.6768052394589E+49 2.3384026197294E+49 1.1692013098647E+49 5.8460065493236E+48 2.9230032746618E+48 1.4615016373309E+48 7.3075081866545E+47 3.6537540933273E+47 1.8268770466636E+47 9.1343852333181E+46 4.5671926166591E+46 2.2835963083295E+46 1.1417981541648E+46 5.7089907708238E+45 2.8544953854119E+45 1.427247692706E+45 7.1362384635298E+44 3.5681192317649E+44 1.7840596158824E+44 8.9202980794122E+43 4.4601490397061E+43 2.2300745198531E+43 1.1150372599265E+43 5.5751862996327E+42 2.7875931498163E+42 1.3937965749082E+42 6.9689828745408E+41 3.4844914372704E+41 1.7422457186352E+41 8.711228593176E+40 4.355614296588E+40 2.177807148294E+40 1.088903574147E+40 5.444517870735E+39 2.7222589353675E+39 1.3611294676838E+39 6.8056473384188E+38 3.4028236692094E+38 1.7014118346047E+38 8.5070591730235E+37 4.2535295865117E+37 2.1267647932559E+37 1.0633823966279E+37 5.3169119831397E+36 2.6584559915698E+36 1.3292279957849E+36 6.6461399789246E+35 3.3230699894623E+35 1.6615349947311E+35 8.3076749736557E+34 4.1538374868279E+34 2.0769187434139E+34 1.038459371707E+34 5.1922968585348E+33 2.5961484292674E+33 1.2980742146337E+33 6.4903710731685E+32 3.2451855365843E+32 1.6225927682921E+32 8.1129638414607E+31 4.0564819207303E+31 2.0282409603652E+31 1.0141204801826E+31 5.0706024009129E+30 2.5353012004565E+30 1.2676506002282E+30 6.3382530011411E+29 3.1691265005706E+29 1.5845632502853E+29 7.9228162514264E+28 3.9614081257132E+28 1.9807040628566E+28 9.903520314283E+27 4.9517601571415E+27 2.4758800785708E+27 1.2379400392854E+27 6.1897001964269E+26 3.0948500982135E+26 1.5474250491067E+26 7.7371252455336E+25 3.8685626227668E+25 1.9342813113834E+25 9.671406556917E+24 4.8357032784585E+24 2.4178516392293E+24 1.2089258196146E+24 6.0446290980731E+23 3.0223145490366E+23 1.5111572745183E+23 7.5557863725914E+22 3.7778931862957E+22 1.8889465931479E+22 9.4447329657393E+21 4.7223664828696E+21 2.3611832414348E+21 1.1805916207174E+21 5.9029581035871E+20 2.9514790517935E+20 1.4757395258968E+20 7.3786976294838E+19 3.6893488147419E+19 1.844674407371E+19 9.2233720368548E+18 4.6116860184274E+18 2.3058430092137E+18 1.1529215046068E+18 5.7646075230342E+17 2.8823037615171E+17 1.4411518807586E+17 7.2057594037928E+16 3.6028797018964E+16 1.8014398509482E+16 9.007199254741E+15 4.5035996273705E+15 2.2517998136852E+15 1.1258999068426E+15 5.6294995342131E+14 2.8147497671066E+14 1.4073748835533E+14 70368744177664 35184372088832 17592186044416 8796093022208 4398046511104 2199023255552 1099511627776 549755813888 274877906944 137438953472 68719476736 34359738368 17179869184 8589934592 4294967296 2147483648 1073741824 536870912 268435456 134217728 67108864 33554432 16777216 8388608 4194304 2097152 1048576 524288 262144 131072 65536 32768 16384 8192 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

The biggest number I could find that PHP could handle was `5.0E+19` and `1E+62` is bigger.

$_GET['int'] = "input" ^ 2 - 1

```
<?php
$int = $_GET['int'];
if($int % 2 == 0){
    $int ++;
}
$test = $_GET['test'];
$x = $test;
$z = 0;
$start = $int;
$br='<br>';
echo "$int".' ';
while($x > 1){
    $x --;
    $z ++;
    $z ++;
    while($int != 1)
    {
        if($int % 2 == 0){
            $int = $int / 2;
        }
        else{
            $int = 3 * $int + 1;
            echo "$int".' ';
            $int = $int / 2;
        }
        echo "$int".' ';
    }
    echo"<br>".' '."<br>";
    $test ++;

    $int = $start + $z;
    echo "$int".' ';
}
?>
```

I did run it agen and it prodused this group befor it did get stuck on INF

```
4.4942328371558E+307 2.2471164185779E+307 1.1235582092889E+307 5.6177910464447E+306 2.8088955232224E+306 1.4044477616112E+306 7.0222388080559E+305 3.511119404028E+305 1.755559702014E+305 8.7777985100699E+304 4.388899255035E+304 2.1944496275175E+304 1.0972248137587E+304 5.4861240687937E+303 2.7430620343968E+303 1.3715310171984E+303 6.8576550859921E+302 3.4288275429961E+302 1.714413771498E+302 8.5720688574901E+301 4.2860344287451E+301 2.1430172143725E+301 1.0715086071863E+301 5.3575430359313E+300 2.6787715179657E+300 1.3393857589828E+300 6.6969287949142E+299 3.3484643974571E+299 1.6742321987285E+299 8.3711609936427E+298 4.1855804968214E+298 2.0927902484107E+298 1.0463951242053E+298 5.2319756210267E+297 2.6159878105133E+297 1.3079939052567E+297 6.5399695262834E+296 3.2699847631417E+296 1.6349923815708E+296 8.1749619078542E+295 4.0874809539271E+295 2.0437404769636E+295 1.0218702384818E+295 5.1093511924089E+294 2.5546755962044E+294 1.2773377981022E+294 6.3866889905111E+293 3.1933444952556E+293 1.5966722476278E+293 7.9833612381389E+292 3.9916806190694E+292 1.9958403095347E+292 9.9792015476736E+291 4.9896007738368E+291 2.4948003869184E+291 1.2474001934592E+291 6.237000967296E+290 3.118500483648E+290 1.559250241824E+290 7.79625120912E+289 3.89812560456E+289 1.94906280228E+289 9.7453140114E+288 4.8726570057E+288 2.43632850285E+288 1.218164251425E+288 6.090821257125E+287 3.0454106285625E+287 1.5227053142812E+287 7.6135265714062E+286 3.8067632857031E+286 1.9033816428516E+286 9.5169082142578E+285 4.7584541071289E+285 2.3792270535645E+285 1.1896135267822E+285 5.9480676339111E+284 2.9740338169556E+284 1.4870169084778E+284 7.4350845423889E+283 3.7175422711945E+283 1.8587711355972E+283 9.2938556779861E+282 4.6469278389931E+282 2.3234639194965E+282 1.1617319597483E+282 5.8086597987413E+281 2.9043298993707E+281 1.4521649496853E+281 7.2608247484267E+280 3.6304123742133E+280 1.8152061871067E+280 9.0760309355333E+279 4.5380154677667E+279 2.2690077338833E+279 1.1345038669417E+279 5.6725193347083E+278 2.8362596673542E+278 1.4181298336771E+278 7.0906491683854E+277 3.5453245841927E+277 1.7726622920964E+277 8.8633114604818E+276 4.4316557302409E+276 2.2158278651204E+276 1.1079139325602E+276 5.5395696628011E+275 2.7697848314006E+275 1.3848924157003E+275 6.9244620785014E+274 3.4622310392507E+274 1.7311155196253E+274 8.6555775981267E+273 4.3277887990634E+273 2.1638943995317E+273 1.0819471997658E+273 5.4097359988292E+272 2.7048679994146E+272 1.3524339997073E+272 6.7621699985365E+271 3.3810849992683E+271 1.6905424996341E+271 8.4527124981706E+270 4.2263562490853E+270 2.1131781245427E+270 1.0565890622713E+270 5.2829453113567E+269 2.6414726556783E+269 1.3207363278392E+269 6.6036816391958E+268 3.3018408195979E+268 1.650920409799E+268 8.2546020489948E+267 4.1273010244974E+267 2.0636505122487E+267 1.0318252561243E+267 5.1591262806217E+266 2.5795631403109E+266 1.2897815701554E+266 6.4489078507772E+265 3.2244539253886E+265 1.6122269626943E+265 8.0611348134715E+264 4.0305674067357E+264 2.0152837033679E+264 1.0076418516839E+264 5.0382092584197E+263 2.5191046292098E+263 1.2595523146049E+263 6.2977615730246E+262 3.1488807865123E+262 1.5744403932561E+262 7.8722019662807E+261 3.9361009831404E+261 1.9680504915702E+261 9.8402524578509E+260 4.9201262289254E+260 2.4600631144627E+260 1.2300315572314E+260 6.1501577861568E+259 3.0750788930784E+259 1.5375394465392E+259 7.687697232696E+258 3.843848616348E+258 1.921924308174E+258 9.60962154087E+257 4.804810770435E+257 2.4024053852175E+257 1.2012026926088E+257 6.0060134630438E+256 3.0030067315219E+256 1.5015033657609E+256 7.5075168288047E+255 3.7537584144024E+255 1.8768792072012E+255 9.3843960360059E+254 4.6921980180029E+254 2.3460990090015E+254 1.1730495045007E+254 5.8652475225037E+253 2.9326237612518E+253 1.4663118806259E+253 7.3315594031296E+252 3.6657797015648E+252 1.8328898507824E+252 9.164449253912E+251 4.582224626956E+251 2.291112313478E+251 1.145556156739E+251 5.727780783695E+250 2.8638903918475E+250 1.4319451959237E+250 7.1597259796187E+249 3.5798629898094E+249 1.7899314949047E+249 8.9496574745234E+248 4.4748287372617E+248 2.2374143686309E+248 1.1187071843154E+248 5.5935359215771E+247 2.7967679607886E+247 1.3983839803943E+247 6.9919199019714E+246 3.4959599509857E+246 1.7479799754929E+246 8.7398998774643E+245 4.3699499387321E+245 2.1849749693661E+245 1.092487484683E+245 5.4624374234152E+244 2.7312187117076E+244 1.3656093558538E+244 6.828046779269E+243 3.4140233896345E+243 1.7070116948172E+243 8.5350584740862E+242 4.2675292370431E+242 2.1337646185216E+242 1.0668823092608E+242 5.3344115463039E+241 2.6672057731519E+241 1.333602886576E+241 6.6680144328799E+240 3.3340072164399E+240 1.66700360822E+240 8.3350180410998E+239 4.1675090205499E+239 2.083754510275E+239 1.0418772551375E+239 5.2093862756874E+238 2.6046931378437E+238 1.3023465689218E+238 6.5117328446092E+237 3.2558664223046E+237 1.6279332111523E+237 8.1396660557615E+236 4.0698330278808E+236 2.0349165139404E+236 1.0174582569702E+236 5.087291284851E+235 2.5436456424255E+235 1.2718228212127E+235 6.3591141060637E+234 3.1795570530319E+234 1.5897785265159E+234 7.9488926325796E+233 3.9744463162898E+233 1.9872231581449E+233 9.9361157907245E+232 4.9680578953623E+232 2.4840289476811E+232 1.2420144738406E+232 6.2100723692028E+231 3.1050361846014E+231 1.5525180923007E+231 7.7625904615035E+230 3.8812952307518E+230 1.9406476153759E+230 9.7032380768794E+229 4.8516190384397E+229 2.4258095192199E+229 1.2129047596099E+229 6.0645237980496E+228 3.0322618990248E+228 1.5161309495124E+228 7.5806547475621E+227 3.790327373781E+227 1.8951636868905E+227 9.4758184344526E+226 4.7379092172263E+226 2.3689546086131E+226 1.1844773043066E+226 5.9223865215329E+225 2.9611932607664E+225 1.4805966303832E+225 7.4029831519161E+224 3.701491575958E+224 1.850745787979E+224 9.2537289398951E+223 4.6268644699475E+223 2.3134322349738E+223 1.1567161174869E+223 5.7835805874344E+222 2.8917902937172E+222 1.4458951468586E+222 7.229475734293E+221 3.6147378671465E+221 1.8073689335733E+221 9.0368446678663E+220 4.5184223339331E+220 2.2592111669666E+220 1.1296055834833E+220 5.6480279174164E+219 2.8240139587082E+219 1.4120069793541E+219 7.0600348967705E+218 3.5300174483853E+218 1.7650087241926E+218 8.8250436209632E+217 4.4125218104816E+217 2.2062609052408E+217 1.1031304526204E+217 5.515652263102E+216 2.757826131551E+216 1.3789130657755E+216 6.8945653288775E+215 3.4472826644387E+215 1.7236413322194E+215 8.6182066610969E+214 4.3091033305484E+214 2.1545516652742E+214 1.0772758326371E+214 5.3863791631855E+213 2.6931895815928E+213 1.3465947907964E+213 6.7329739539819E+212 3.366486976991E+212 1.6832434884955E+212 8.4162174424774E+211 4.2081087212387E+211 2.1040543606193E+211 1.0520271803097E+211 5.2601359015484E+210 2.6300679507742E+210 1.3150339753871E+210 6.5751698769355E+209 3.2875849384677E+209 1.6437924692339E+209 8.2189623461693E+208 4.1094811730847E+208 2.0547405865423E+208 1.0273702932712E+208 5.1368514663558E+207 2.5684257331779E+207 1.284212866589E+207 6.4210643329448E+206 3.2105321664724E+206 1.6052660832362E+206 8.026330416181E+205 4.0131652080905E+205 2.0065826040452E+205 1.0032913020226E+205 5.0164565101131E+204 2.5082282550566E+204 1.2541141275283E+204 6.2705706376414E+203 3.1352853188207E+203 1.5676426594103E+203 7.8382132970517E+202 3.9191066485259E+202 1.9595533242629E+202 9.7977666213147E+201 4.8988833106573E+201 2.4494416553287E+201 1.2247208276643E+201 6.1236041383217E+200 3.0618020691608E+200 1.5309010345804E+200 7.6545051729021E+199 3.827252586451E+199 1.9136262932255E+199 9.5681314661276E+198 4.7840657330638E+198 2.3920328665319E+198 1.196016433266E+198 5.9800821663298E+197 2.9900410831649E+197 1.4950205415824E+197 7.4751027079122E+196 3.7375513539561E+196 1.8687756769781E+196 9.3438783848903E+195 4.6719391924451E+195 2.3359695962226E+195 1.1679847981113E+195 5.8399239905564E+194 2.9199619952782E+194 1.4599809976391E+194 7.2999049881955E+193 3.6499524940978E+193 1.8249762470489E+193 9.1248812352444E+192 4.5624406176222E+192 2.2812203088111E+192 1.1406101544055E+192 5.7030507720277E+191 2.8515253860139E+191 1.4257626930069E+191 7.1288134650347E+190 3.5644067325173E+190 1.7822033662587E+190 8.9110168312934E+189 4.4555084156467E+189 2.2277542078233E+189 1.1138771039117E+189 5.5693855195583E+188 2.7846927597792E+188 1.3923463798896E+188 6.9617318994479E+187 3.480865949724E+187 1.740432974862E+187 8.7021648743099E+186 4.351082437155E+186 2.1755412185775E+186 1.0877706092887E+186 5.4388530464437E+185 2.7194265232218E+185 1.3597132616109E+185 6.7985663080546E+184 3.3992831540273E+184 1.6996415770137E+184 8.4982078850683E+183 4.2491039425341E+183 2.1245519712671E+183 1.0622759856335E+183 5.3113799281677E+182 2.6556899640838E+182 1.3278449820419E+182 6.6392249102096E+181 3.3196124551048E+181 1.6598062275524E+181 8.299031137762E+180 4.149515568881E+180 2.0747577844405E+180 1.0373788922202E+180 5.1868944611012E+179 2.5934472305506E+179 1.2967236152753E+179 6.4836180763766E+178 3.2418090381883E+178 1.6209045190941E+178 8.1045225954707E+177 4.0522612977353E+177 2.0261306488677E+177 1.0130653244338E+177 5.0653266221692E+176 2.5326633110846E+176 1.2663316555423E+176 6.3316582777115E+175 3.1658291388557E+175 1.5829145694279E+175 7.9145728471393E+174 3.9572864235697E+174 1.9786432117848E+174 9.8932160589242E+173 4.9466080294621E+173 2.473304014731E+173 1.2366520073655E+173 6.1832600368276E+172 3.0916300184138E+172 1.5458150092069E+172 7.7290750460345E+171 3.8645375230173E+171 1.9322687615086E+171 9.6613438075431E+170 4.8306719037716E+170 2.4153359518858E+170 1.2076679759429E+170 6.0383398797145E+169 3.0191699398572E+169 1.5095849699286E+169 7.5479248496431E+168 3.7739624248215E+168 1.8869812124108E+168 9.4349060620539E+167 4.7174530310269E+167 2.3587265155135E+167 1.1793632577567E+167 5.8968162887837E+166 2.9484081443918E+166 1.4742040721959E+166 7.3710203609796E+165 3.6855101804898E+165 1.8427550902449E+165 9.2137754512245E+164 4.6068877256122E+164 2.3034438628061E+164 1.1517219314031E+164 5.7586096570153E+163 2.8793048285076E+163 1.4396524142538E+163 7.1982620712691E+162 3.5991310356346E+162 1.7995655178173E+162 8.9978275890864E+161 4.4989137945432E+161 2.2494568972716E+161 1.1247284486358E+161 5.623642243179E+160 2.8118211215895E+160 1.4059105607947E+160 7.0295528039737E+159 3.5147764019869E+159 1.7573882009934E+159 8.7869410049672E+158 4.3934705024836E+158 2.1967352512418E+158 1.0983676256209E+158 5.4918381281045E+157 2.7459190640522E+157 1.3729595320261E+157 6.8647976601306E+156 3.4323988300653E+156 1.7161994150327E+156 8.5809970751633E+155 4.2904985375816E+155 2.1452492687908E+155 1.0726246343954E+155 5.363123171977E+154 2.6815615859885E+154 1.3407807929943E+154 6.7039039649713E+153 3.3519519824856E+153 1.6759759912428E+153 8.3798799562141E+152 4.1899399781071E+152 2.0949699890535E+152 1.0474849945268E+152 5.2374249726338E+151 2.6187124863169E+151 1.3093562431585E+151 6.5467812157923E+150 3.2733906078961E+150 1.6366953039481E+150 8.1834765197404E+149 4.0917382598702E+149 2.0458691299351E+149 1.0229345649675E+149 5.1146728248377E+148 2.5573364124189E+148 1.2786682062094E+148 6.3933410310472E+147 3.1966705155236E+147 1.5983352577618E+147 7.9916762888089E+146 3.9958381444045E+146 1.9979190722022E+146 9.9895953610112E+145 4.9947976805056E+145 2.4973988402528E+145 1.2486994201264E+145 6.243497100632E+144 3.121748550316E+144 1.560874275158E+144 7.80437137579E+143 3.902185687895E+143 1.9510928439475E+143 9.7554642197375E+142 4.8777321098687E+142 2.4388660549344E+142 1.2194330274672E+142 6.0971651373359E+141 3.048582568668E+141 1.524291284334E+141 7.6214564216699E+140 3.810728210835E+140 1.9053641054175E+140 9.5268205270874E+139 4.7634102635437E+139 2.3817051317718E+139 1.1908525658859E+139 5.9542628294296E+138 2.9771314147148E+138 1.4885657073574E+138 7.442828536787E+137 3.7214142683935E+137 1.8607071341968E+137 9.3035356709838E+136 4.6517678354919E+136 2.3258839177459E+136 1.162941958873E+136 5.8147097943649E+135 2.9073548971824E+135 1.4536774485912E+135 7.2683872429561E+134 3.634193621478E+134 1.817096810739E+134 9.0854840536951E+133 4.5427420268475E+133 2.2713710134238E+133 1.1356855067119E+133 5.6784275335594E+132 2.8392137667797E+132 1.4196068833899E+132 7.0980344169493E+131 3.5490172084746E+131 1.7745086042373E+131 8.8725430211866E+130 4.4362715105933E+130 2.2181357552967E+130 1.1090678776483E+130 5.5453393882416E+129 2.7726696941208E+129 1.3863348470604E+129 6.931674235302E+128 3.465837117651E+128 1.7329185588255E+128 8.6645927941275E+127 4.3322963970638E+127 2.1661481985319E+127 1.0830740992659E+127 5.4153704963297E+126 2.7076852481649E+126 1.3538426240824E+126 6.7692131204121E+125 3.3846065602061E+125 1.692303280103E+125 8.4615164005152E+124 4.2307582002576E+124 2.1153791001288E+124 1.0576895500644E+124 5.288447750322E+123 2.644223875161E+123 1.3221119375805E+123 6.6105596879025E+122 3.3052798439512E+122 1.6526399219756E+122 8.2631996098781E+121 4.1315998049391E+121 2.0657999024695E+121 1.0328999512348E+121 5.1644997561738E+120 2.5822498780869E+120 1.2911249390435E+120 6.4556246952173E+119 3.2278123476086E+119 1.6139061738043E+119 8.0695308690216E+118 4.0347654345108E+118 2.0173827172554E+118 1.0086913586277E+118 5.0434567931385E+117 2.5217283965692E+117 1.2608641982846E+117 6.3043209914231E+116 3.1521604957116E+116 1.5760802478558E+116 7.8804012392789E+115 3.9402006196394E+115 1.9701003098197E+115 9.8505015490986E+114 4.9252507745493E+114 2.4626253872747E+114 1.2313126936373E+114 6.1565634681866E+113 3.0782817340933E+113 1.5391408670467E+113 7.6957043352333E+112 3.8478521676166E+112 1.9239260838083E+112 9.6196304190416E+111 4.8098152095208E+111 2.4049076047604E+111 1.2024538023802E+111 6.012269011901E+110 3.0061345059505E+110 1.5030672529753E+110 7.5153362648763E+109 3.7576681324381E+109 1.8788340662191E+109 9.3941703310953E+108 4.6970851655477E+108 2.3485425827738E+108 1.1742712913869E+108 5.8713564569346E+107 2.9356782284673E+107 1.4678391142336E+107 7.3391955711682E+106 3.6695977855841E+106 1.8347988927921E+106 9.1739944639603E+105 4.5869972319801E+105 2.2934986159901E+105 1.146749307995E+105 5.7337465399752E+104 2.8668732699876E+104 1.4334366349938E+104 7.167183174969E+103 3.5835915874845E+103 1.7917957937422E+103 8.9589789687112E+102 4.4794894843556E+102 2.2397447421778E+102 1.1198723710889E+102 5.5993618554445E+101 2.7996809277223E+101 1.3998404638611E+101 6.9992023193056E+100 3.4996011596528E+100 1.7498005798264E+100 8.749002899132E+99 4.374501449566E+99 2.187250724783E+99 1.0936253623915E+99 5.4681268119575E+98 2.7340634059788E+98 1.3670317029894E+98 6.8351585149469E+97 3.4175792574735E+97 1.7087896287367E+97 8.5439481436836E+96 4.2719740718418E+96 2.1359870359209E+96 1.0679935179605E+96 5.3399675898023E+95 2.6699837949011E+95 1.3349918974506E+95 6.6749594872528E+94 3.3374797436264E+94 1.6687398718132E+94 8.3436993590661E+93 4.171849679533E+93 2.0859248397665E+93 1.0429624198833E+93 5.2148120994163E+92 2.6074060497081E+92 1.3037030248541E+92 6.5185151242704E+91 3.2592575621352E+91 1.6296287810676E+91 8.1481439053379E+90 4.074071952669E+90 2.0370359763345E+90 1.0185179881672E+90 5.0925899408362E+89 2.5462949704181E+89 1.2731474852091E+89 6.3657374260453E+88 3.1828687130226E+88 1.5914343565113E+88 7.9571717825566E+87 3.9785858912783E+87 1.9892929456391E+87 9.9464647281957E+86 4.9732323640979E+86 2.4866161820489E+86 1.2433080910245E+86 6.2165404551223E+85 3.1082702275612E+85 1.5541351137806E+85 7.7706755689029E+84 3.8853377844515E+84 1.9426688922257E+84 9.7133444611286E+83 4.8566722305643E+83 2.4283361152822E+83 1.2141680576411E+83 6.0708402882054E+82 3.0354201441027E+82 1.5177100720514E+82 7.5885503602568E+81 3.7942751801284E+81 1.8971375900642E+81 9.4856879503209E+80 4.7428439751605E+80 2.3714219875802E+80 1.1857109937901E+80 5.9285549689506E+79 2.9642774844753E+79 1.4821387422376E+79 7.4106937111882E+78 3.7053468555941E+78 1.8526734277971E+78 9.2633671389853E+77 4.6316835694926E+77 2.3158417847463E+77 1.1579208923732E+77 5.7896044618658E+76 2.8948022309329E+76 1.4474011154665E+76 7.2370055773323E+75 3.6185027886661E+75 1.8092513943331E+75 9.0462569716653E+74 4.5231284858327E+74 2.2615642429163E+74 1.1307821214582E+74 5.6539106072908E+73 2.8269553036454E+73 1.4134776518227E+73 7.0673882591135E+72 3.5336941295568E+72 1.7668470647784E+72 8.8342353238919E+71 4.417117661946E+71 2.208558830973E+71 1.1042794154865E+71 5.5213970774325E+70 2.7606985387162E+70 1.3803492693581E+70 6.9017463467906E+69 3.4508731733953E+69 1.7254365866976E+69 8.6271829334882E+68 4.3135914667441E+68 2.1567957333721E+68 1.078397866686E+68 5.3919893334301E+67 2.6959946667151E+67 1.3479973333575E+67 6.7399866667877E+66 3.3699933333938E+66 1.6849966666969E+66 8.4249833334846E+65 4.2124916667423E+65 2.1062458333711E+65 1.0531229166856E+65 5.2656145834279E+64 2.6328072917139E+64 1.316403645857E+64 6.5820182292848E+63 3.2910091146424E+63 1.6455045573212E+63 8.227522786606E+62 4.113761393303E+62 2.0568806966515E+62 1.0284403483258E+62 5.1422017416288E+61 2.5711008708144E+61 1.2855504354072E+61 6.427752177036E+60 3.213876088518E+60 1.606938044259E+60 8.034690221295E+59 4.0173451106475E+59 2.0086725553237E+59 1.0043362776619E+59 5.0216813883093E+58 2.5108406941547E+58 1.2554203470773E+58 6.2771017353867E+57 3.1385508676933E+57 1.5692754338467E+57 7.8463771692334E+56 3.9231885846167E+56 1.9615942923083E+56 9.8079714615417E+55 4.9039857307708E+55 2.4519928653854E+55 1.2259964326927E+55 6.1299821634636E+54 3.0649910817318E+54 1.5324955408659E+54 7.6624777043294E+53 3.8312388521647E+53 1.9156194260824E+53 9.5780971304118E+52 4.7890485652059E+52 2.394524282603E+52 1.1972621413015E+52 5.9863107065074E+51 2.9931553532537E+51 1.4965776766268E+51 7.4828883831342E+50 3.7414441915671E+50 1.8707220957836E+50 9.3536104789178E+49 4.6768052394589E+49 2.3384026197294E+49 1.1692013098647E+49 5.8460065493236E+48 2.9230032746618E+48 1.4615016373309E+48 7.3075081866545E+47 3.6537540933273E+47 1.8268770466636E+47 9.1343852333181E+46 4.5671926166591E+46 2.2835963083295E+46 1.1417981541648E+46 5.7089907708238E+45 2.8544953854119E+45 1.427247692706E+45 7.1362384635298E+44 3.5681192317649E+44 1.7840596158824E+44 8.9202980794122E+43 4.4601490397061E+43 2.2300745198531E+43 1.1150372599265E+43 5.5751862996327E+42 2.7875931498163E+42 1.3937965749082E+42 6.9689828745408E+41 3.4844914372704E+41 1.7422457186352E+41 8.711228593176E+40 4.355614296588E+40 2.177807148294E+40 1.088903574147E+40 5.444517870735E+39 2.7222589353675E+39 1.3611294676838E+39 6.8056473384188E+38 3.4028236692094E+38 1.7014118346047E+38 8.5070591730235E+37 4.2535295865117E+37 2.1267647932559E+37 1.0633823966279E+37 5.3169119831397E+36 2.6584559915698E+36 1.3292279957849E+36 6.6461399789246E+35 3.3230699894623E+35 1.6615349947311E+35 8.3076749736557E+34 4.1538374868279E+34 2.0769187434139E+34 1.038459371707E+34 5.1922968585348E+33 2.5961484292674E+33 1.2980742146337E+33 6.4903710731685E+32 3.2451855365843E+32 1.6225927682921E+32 8.1129638414607E+31 4.0564819207303E+31 2.0282409603652E+31 1.0141204801826E+31 5.0706024009129E+30 2.5353012004565E+30 1.2676506002282E+30 6.3382530011411E+29 3.1691265005706E+29 1.5845632502853E+29 7.9228162514264E+28 3.9614081257132E+28 1.9807040628566E+28 9.903520314283E+27 4.9517601571415E+27 2.4758800785708E+27 1.2379400392854E+27 6.1897001964269E+26 3.0948500982135E+26 1.5474250491067E+26 7.7371252455336E+25 3.8685626227668E+25 1.9342813113834E+25 9.671406556917E+24 4.8357032784585E+24 2.4178516392293E+24 1.2089258196146E+24 6.0446290980731E+23 3.0223145490366E+23 1.5111572745183E+23 7.5557863725914E+22 3.7778931862957E+22 1.8889465931479E+22 9.4447329657393E+21 4.7223664828696E+21 2.3611832414348E+21 1.1805916207174E+21 5.9029581035871E+20 2.9514790517935E+20 1.4757395258968E+20 7.3786976294838E+19 3.6893488147419E+19 1.844674407371E+19 9.2233720368548E+18 4.6116860184274E+18 2.3058430092137E+18 1.1529215046068E+18 5.7646075230342E+17 2.8823037615171E+17 1.4411518807586E+17 7.2057594037928E+16 3.6028797018964E+16 1.8014398509482E+16 9.007199254741E+15 4.5035996273705E+15 2.2517998136852E+15 1.1258999068426E+15 5.6294995342131E+14 2.8147497671066E+14 1.4073748835533E+14 70368744177664 35184372088832 17592186044416 8796093022208 4398046511104 2199023255552 1099511627776 549755813888 274877906944 137438953472 68719476736 34359738368 17179869184 8589934592 4294967296 2147483648 1073741824 536870912 268435456 134217728 67108864 33554432 16777216 8388608 4194304 2097152 1048576 524288 262144 131072 65536 32768 16384 8192 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
```

Comment: What script did you run?

Comment: Maybe paste that formatted into the question?

Comment: I don't get how I should insert the code to the question

Answer (score 2):

Largest integer that can be stored in PHP variable is called [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). PHP has two extensions that can handle arbitrarily big numbers: [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), that operates only on integers, and [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/pl/book.bc.php) that allows calculations on any kind of numbers.

As for floats, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650324/maximum-float-value-in-php).