# PHP round() function does not round the number

Tags: php, rounding

It looks like PHP round() does not behave as expected. Look at the following code:

```
log_rec("BEFORE ROUNDING","x", $x);
$x = round($x, 3);
log_rec("AFTER ROUNDING","x", $x);
```

where log_rec() is simply a function of mine to write a record in a log file,
and $x value is initially set to 3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375.

I expect $x to be 3.34 after rounding.

Here is the result in log file:

```
▶"BEFORE ROUNDING"■"x"■3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375■
▶"AFTER ROUNDING"■"x"■3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375■
```

No change. What am I doing wrong? I am using PHP 7.4.26.

NOTE: I need to round the number, that is, to obtain another float number. So, number_format() is **not** a solution.

**UPDATE**

I decided to use a different approach, that is to use

```
log_rec("BEFORE ROUNDING","x", $x);
$x= intval(100 * $x)/100;
log_rec("AFTER ROUNDING","x", $x);
```

I expected now

```
▶"BEFORE ROUNDING"■"x"■3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375■
▶"AFTER ROUNDING"■"x"■3.34■
```

but I still get

```
▶"BEFORE ROUNDING"■"x"■3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375■
▶"AFTER ROUNDING"■"x"■3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375■
```

Now I am totally confused. This is a sequence of three well defined instructions. No other code should create some collateral effect.

Any idea?

**PS: WHERE THE NUMBER COMES FROM?**

Someone asked where that big number comes from.
From a JSON file. What is strange is that that number in JSON is 3.334, but after json_decode() something strange happens: if I use var_dump() I get 3.334 but if I use print_r() I get that big number.

Comment: If you set `$x=3.3399999999999;` it will work, not quite sure what this says about your number other than PHP cannot cope with that many decimal places

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650324/maximum-float-value-in-php

Comment: `$x = 3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375;` would result in $x having the value `3.34` _before_ any rounding already, see https://3v4l.org/aXk0u So you can't have an actual float with that value, this is outside of the precision a float can handle to begin with. So you must have something else then - a string value to be used with bc_math functions perhaps?

Comment: Well, I do not set that number, but I get it from an application that calculates it.

Comment: Many decimal fractions can't be represented exactly in binary floating point (just as `1/3` can't be represented exactly in decimal), this may be one of them.

Comment: This is why rounding is normally done when formatting the number for human presentation, not when calculating internally.

Comment: Just consider that I use print_r to save that record in the log. The number should be 3.334 since the beginning. But print_r() prints a longer number. No idea why.

Comment: But why print_r display a long number from a short value decoded from a JSON file whereas var_dump displays the right one? Is there a way to know EXACTLY which is the number stored in that variable?

Comment: @Barmar what if I really want that a variable would contain a floating point number with only two decimals? A real round. I tried `$x= intval(100 * $x)/100;` but I still get a long numer when I print_r() it. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: You can't get it, there's no representation in binary floating point for that exact number.

Comment: There are different algorithms for printing floating point numbers. One way is to consider all the binary digits significant and show that number precisely, which is what `print_r` is doing. Another is to determine the range of decimal numbers that all produce the same binary result, and print a number in that range with the fewest trailing zeros, which is what `var_dump` does.

Comment: @Barmar OK, I understand that, but why $x= intval(100 * $x)/100; does not return 3.34? intval should truncate my number.

Comment: I'll just say it again. 3.34 can't be represented exactly in floating point. The closest number is 3.33999999...

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right, because I tried the following in Python:
| x = 3.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375
| y = x * 100
| z = int(y)
| w = z / 100
| b = x == w
| print(x, y, z, w, b)
and I got
[3.34 334.0 334 3.34 True].
What is puzzling me is that when I programmed in C++ or FORTRAN I had not such problems.

Comment: It depends on how the number formatting algorithm is designed.